# Add multiple admin in user mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, activeadmin

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => {"admin@abc.com","app@xyz.com"}
end
```

Is this the right way to add multiple default email accounts??

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails doesn't understand multiple `from` addresses. You should use plain string for this, separating emails by commas:

```
default from: [email1, email2, email3].join(',')
```

Be careful though. I'm not sure this feature is widely [supported](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/200181878-Can-I-send-from-multiple-FROM-addresses-).

**Update**

A question was asked in a comment why to format multiple from addresses if Rails does not support this. I researched it a bit and found the RFC-2822 specification, [section 3.6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.2) stating the following:

> The from field consists of the field name "From" and a comma-separated list of one or more mailbox specifications.

Comment: `Rails doesn't understand multiple from addresses`, right, but why do you write as answer how to join many addresses?

Comment: @TimoSchilling because it looks like you can still send using many FROM addresses. What's wrong with `from: 'email1@example.com, email2@example.com'`?

Comment: @TimoSchilling I found RFC-2822 specification, see the link in my answer